# Save options radios or checkbox

Tags: laravel, save

I want to save radio from form in database but I get "on" in the database, I don't know why.

I tried to use HTML form with labels, radios and checkbox but I see in the database saving "on".

Controller :

```
public function store(Request $request, Survey $survey) 
  {
    // remove the token
    $arr = $request->except('_token');
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
      $newAnswer = new Answer();
      if (! is_array( $value )) {
        $newValue = $value['answer'];
      } else {
        $newValue = json_encode($value['answer']);
      }
      $newAnswer->answer = $newValue;
      $newAnswer->question_id = $key;
      $newAnswer->user_id = Auth::id();
      $newAnswer->survey_id = $survey->id;

      $newAnswer->save();

      $answerArray[] = $newAnswer;
    };
    return redirect()->action('SurveyController@view_survey_answers', [$survey->id]);
  }
```

view :

```
{!! Form::open(array('action'=>array('AnswerController@store', $survey->id))) !!}
          @forelse ($survey->questions as $key=>$question)
            <p class="flow-text">Question {{ $key+1 }} - {{ $question->title }}</p>
                @if($question->question_type === 'text')
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="answer" type="text" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]">
                    <label for="answer">Answer</label>
                  </div>
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'textarea')
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]"></textarea>
                    <label for="textarea1">Textarea</label>
                  </div>
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'radio')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                    <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                      <input name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" type="radio" id="{{ $key }}" />
                      <label for="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</label>
                    </p>
                  @endforeach
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                  <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="something{{ $key }}" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" />
                    <label for="something{{$key}}">{{ $value }}</label>
                  </p>
                  @endforeach
                @endif 
              <div class="divider" style="margin:10px 10px;"></div>
          @empty
            <span class='flow-text center-align'>Nothing to show</span>
          @endforelse
        {{ Form::submit('Submit Survey', array('class'=>'btn waves-effect waves-light')) }}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, what do you want instead of 'on'?

Comment: this is data saved on database not the option value

Comment: None of your radios or checkboxes has a value attribute

Comment: they have from the question db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give a value attribute to your checkbox and radio inputs, for example something like this:

```
<input name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" type="radio" id="{{ $key }}" value="{{ $key}}"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="something{{ $key }}" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" value="{{ $key}}"/>
```